# How do 301 redirect with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have url

```
/en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage%E2%80%8B
```

and I try

```
Redirect 301 /en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage\%E2\%80\%8B /en
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+ /en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage%E2%80%8B
RewriteRule ^ /en [R=301,L]
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage\%E2\%80\%8B /en
```

But any version don't work. How I can redirect from this url?

Comment: You want to redirect `/en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage%E2%80%8B` to `/en/` ?

Comment: Yes, I want redirect to `/en`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/parlour-profile/massage-parlour-anna-berry-massage-louise-sensual-massage\xE2\x80\x8B/?$ /en? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`\xMN` is used in `RewriteRule` pattern to match `%MN` in URL.

Comment: I try it and it is not work. I don't understand why http://joxi.ru/BA0blk9uJkXodm

Comment: You didn't read my answer carefully. I wrote use this as **first rule**. Move this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and retest.

Comment: Suddenly! But why? Can you explain? Why should this line be at the top? And if I need to add a few more?
Thank you!

Comment: Because other rule in your .htaccess is rewriting every URL to `index.php` and that changes `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php`